# Reset focus to default after Popup LostFocus

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I'm observing that when the Popup control loses focus it returns focus back to the object that initiated the Popup.  So basically this sequence of events.

1. Textbox GotFocus fires and I open the popup
2. When finished with the Popup user clicks anywhere outside Popup to activate LostFocus
3. LostFocus activates, but immediately after GotFocus for the object in step 1 (Textbox) executes - relaunching the popup.

My question, is there a way to reset focus to whatever the default is when you first start an app?  I want to prevent it from returning focus back to the control that launched the popup.

EDIT: I removed LostFocus event because I found it wasn't necessary in order to remove the popup from view when user taps away.

```
    Popup p;
    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        p = new Popup();
        p.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
        //p.LostFocus += p_LostFocus;

    }


    private void m_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p.IsOpen != true)
        {
            // Create some content to show in the popup. Typically you would 
            // create a user control.
            Border border = new Border();
            border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

            StackPanel panel1 = new StackPanel();
            panel1.FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            panel1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30));

            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Content = ".";
            button1.Margin = new Thickness(5.0);
            button1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 90, 90, 90));
            button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Feedback_Click);

            TextBlock textblock1 = new TextBlock();
            textblock1.Text = "";
            textblock1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
            textblock1.Margin = new Thickness(5.0);
            panel1.Children.Add(textblock1);
            panel1.Children.Add(button1);

            border.Child = panel1;

            // Set the Child property of Popup to the border 
            // which contains a stackpanel, textblock and button.
            p.Child = border;

            // Set where the popup will show up on the screen.
            p.VerticalOffset = 400;
            p.HorizontalOffset = 100;

            // Open the popup.
            p.IsOpen = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you programmatically focus on something else when LostFocus activates? On the main grid or something neutral?

Comment: @igrali I suppose, I just don't know which UI element is the correct one to change focus to.  Also I tried to add this conditional if (p.IsOpen != true) But even after the popup disappears when debugging (when click outside popup) p.IsOpen still equals to true.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to whatever except the TextBox which triggers the popup opening? :)

Comment: @igrali Where would I do this?  I can't use LostFocus event anymore because it gets triggered even when I click buttons inside the popup. So that's not an option. I tried Closed event but that doesn't trigger when I click away.

Comment: @igrali I found the problem it was the textbox that was executing it GotFocus event when the popup closed.  Sort of like when you use the keyboard and close it, focus return back to the textbox.  I'm switching to a textblock instead.